# Nested Select Query Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Right, I am attempting to construct a nested SELECT query in Oracle SQL. The objective is, to SUM values of time (stored as NUMBERS) and then multiply by a hourly rate. This is happening over many "cases" and "clients". Then, extract the top 25% of the results if there were DESC in monetary order.

I will provide the two scripts I have started. One is considerably more useful than the other but neither work.

Script 1:

```
    SELECT  client.client_id,
        client.first_name,
        client.surname,
        case.case_id,
        CONCAT(SUM(note.time_spent), CONCAT(' ', 'Hours')) AS total_time_spent
FROM    (SELECT total_time_spent,
                solicitor.solicitor_id,
                rate.solicitor_id,
                CONCAT('£', CONCAT(total_time_spent*rate.rate_per_hour)) AS total
        FROM    rate,
                solicitor
        INNER JOIN rate
        ON rate.solicitor_id = solicitor.solicitor_id
        GROUP BY solicitor_id)  
    note, 
    case
INNER JOIN client
ON case.case_id = note.case_id
INNER JOIN note
ON rate.solicitor_id = solicitor.solicitor_id
GROUP BY    note.client_id,
            note.solicitor_id
ORDER BY case.case_id,
         client.client_id;
```

Script 2:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (
SELECT  client.client_id,
        client.first_name,
        client.surname
        CONCAT('£', SUM(note.time_spent*rate.rate_per_hour)) AS total
FROM    rate, note, client, case
WHERE note.solicitor_id = solicitor.solicitor_id
    AND solicitor.solicitor_id = rate.solicitor_id
    AND note.case_id = case.case_id
    AND case.client_id = client.client_id
ORDER BY total DESC
) WHERE ROWNUM <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIENT)/4;
```

Here are the TABLE CREATE scripts:

CREATE case

```
CREATE TABLE case
(
case_id         NUMBER(4),
client_id       NUMBER(4),
description     VARCHAR(100) CONSTRAINT case_description_nn NOT NULL,
date_filed      DATE CONSTRAINT case_date_filled_nn NOT NULL,
date_closed     DATE,

CONSTRAINT case_client_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client (client_id),
CONSTRAINT case_pk PRIMARY KEY (case_id)
);
```

CREATE NOTE

```
CREATE TABLE note
(
note_id         NUMBER(4),
case_id         NUMBER(4),
solicitor_id    NUMBER(2),
content         VARCHAR(500) CONSTRAINT note_content_nn NOT NULL,
time_spent      NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT note_time_spent_nn  NOT NULL, -- I have made the assumption that time taken is recorded as an integer value, e.g. 6 [Hours] --
date_added      DATE DEFAULT (sysdate) CONSTRAINT note_date_addedd_nn NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT note_solicitor_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (solicitor_id) REFERENCES solicitor (solicitor_id),
CONSTRAINT note_case_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (case_id) REFERENCES case (case_id),
CONSTRAINT note_pk PRIMARY KEY (note_id)
);
```

CREATE SOLICITOR

```
CREATE TABLE solicitor
(
solicitor_id    NUMBER(2),
first_name      CHAR(15) CONSTRAINT solicitor_first_name_nn NOT NULL,
surname         CHAR(20) CONSTRAINT solicitor_surname_nn NOT NULL,
telephone       VARCHAR(11) CONSTRAINT solicitor_telephone_nn NOT NULL,
email_address   VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT solicitor_email_address_nn NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT solicitor_pk PRIMARY KEY (solicitor_id)
);
```

CREATE RATE

```
CREATE TABLE rate
(
rate_id         NUMBER(2),
solicitor_id    NUMBER(2),
rate_per_hour   DECIMAL(19,4) CONSTRAINT rate_rate_per_hour_nn NOT NULL,
start_date      DATE CONSTRAINT rate_start_date_nn NOT NULL,
end_date        DATE,

CONSTRAINT rate_solicitor_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (solicitor_id) REFERENCES solicitor (solicitor_id),
CONSTRAINT rate_pk PRIMARY KEY (rate_id)
);
```

CREATE CLIENT

```
CREATE TABLE client
(
client_id       NUMBER(4),
first_name      CHAR(15) CONSTRAINT client_first_name_nn NOT NULL,
surname         CHAR(20) CONSTRAINT client_surname_nn NOT NULL,
address         VARCHAR(35) CONSTRAINT client_address_nn NOT NULL,
postcode        VARCHAR(8)  CONSTRAINT client_postcode_nn NOT NUll,
telephone       VARCHAR(11) CONSTRAINT client_telephone_nn NOT NULL,
email_address   VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT client_email_address_nn NOT NUll,

CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);
```

Comment: In your second query, you need to have a numeric field that is just the sum i.e. not concatenated with the pound sign. and then try and order by that column... that I think should work..

Comment: @vmachan Thanks, so separate out those two operations?

Comment: Yes, I think you would need to have 2 fields - one with the pound sign which you use for display purposes and the other the numeric one which you use to do the order by..  both will be SELECTed in the inner query, you can then skip or choose which fields you want in your outer select

Comment: What is `total_time_spent` supposed to represent, and what is it to be grouped by? Which query do you consider to be the "more useful"? Why is the "less useful" query included? Also, please edit the question and include the DDL for the tables. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis total_time_spent represents the total value of time values from different rows. It should be grouped by case.case_id. The second I consider more useful because it makes more logical sense. I included it because there may be parts which are correct. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT  client.client_id,
                client.first_name,
                client.surname,
                CONCAT('£', SUM(note.time_spent*rate.rate_per_hour)) AS total
        FROM rate, note, client, case, solicitor
        WHERE  note.solicitor_id = solicitor.solicitor_id
        AND solicitor.solicitor_id = rate.solicitor_id
        AND note.case_id = case.case_id 
        AND case.client_id = client.client_id
    GROUP BY    client.client_id,
                client.first_name,
                client.surname
  ORDER BY total DESC
) WHERE ROWNUM <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client)/4
ORDER BY total ASC;
```